# angular-directive has dynamically set scope variables which is to be accessed in controller

Tags: angularjs, variables, angularjs-directive, scope, directive

To help you with the context, i want to take project name as input from the user. Number of projects can vary in number from person to person so in the form we have a default text box and user can add new text boxes by clicking on the button "Add more project name"

I have written an angular directive which appends text box in the form. Now on submit of form we need to access the data of the text boxes in the controller. We are able to dynamically assign an ng-model variable.

But we are unable to fetch the dynamically set scope variable in the controller. I know how to set the pre-defined scope variable to be access in the controller but here scope variable is dynamic and we can't pre-define it. Find my directive code below:

```
b2rApp.directive('addTextField', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'AECM',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        subCatArray: "="

    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        elem.bind('click', function() {

            scope.getModel = function(model_prefix) {
                return model_prefix + parseInt(scope.subCatArray.length-1);
            }
            var fragment = $compile('<label><input type="text" name="input" ng-change="testVal()" ng-model=' + scope.getModel("sub_project_name_") + '></label>')(scope);
            var sibling = elem.parent().find('div');
            //console.log(fragment, sibling[1]);
            sibling[1].insertBefore(fragment[0],sibling[1].querySelector('button'));
            //angular.element(sibling).find('div').find('button').insertBefore(fragment);

        })
    }
}
```

});

```
<label>Project name:
                <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="project_name">
            </label>
            </br>
            <div class='subproject'>
            <div>
                <label>Sub- project name: </br>
                    <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="sub_project_name_0">
                </label>
                </div>
                <button class="remove-text-field" removeSubCategory> - Remove </button>
            </div>

            </br>
        </div>
        <button class="add-text-field" sub-cat-array="scarray" ng-click="addNewSubCategory()">+ Add more subproject</button>
        </br>
        <p>Queue:{{queue}}</p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Here is my controller code:

```
//Initialize the array for storing sub-project names by adding text boxes dynamically
$rootScope.scarray = [{
    'index': 0
}];

//To create a new project to the existing process
$scope.submitProject = function() {
    console.log($rootScope.scarray);
    angular.forEach($rootScope.scarray, function(value, abc) {
    var sub_project_name = value.index ; 
    }, 
};
```

I hope i have been able to clearly define my problem. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think in angular way.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81fc3pzz/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    this.projects = [{
      name: "Stuart",
      text: "Hello <b>Bob</b>"
    }, {
      name: "Bob",
      text: "Hello <strong>Stuart</strong>"
    }, {
      name: "Kevin",
      text: "Hello <i>Kevin</i>"
    }];
    this.addNewSubCategory = function() {
      this.projects.push({
        name: "",
        text: ""
      });
    };
    this.removeSubCategory = function(index) {
      this.projects.splice(index, 1);
    };
    //To create a new project to the existing process
    this.submitProject = function() {
      console.log(this.projects, this.project_name);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as ex">
    <form ng-submit="ex.submitProject()">
      <label>Project name:
        <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="ex.project_name">
      </label>
      <br>
      <div class='subproject' ng-repeat="project in ex.projects">
        <div>
          <label>Sub- project name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="project.name">
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="remove-text-field" ng-click="ex.removeSubCategory($index)"> - Remove </button>
      </div>

      <br>
      <button ng-click="ex.addNewSubCategory()">+ Add more subproject</button>
      <br>
      <p>Queue:{{queue}}</p>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```